# Nginx proxy_pass domain to sub directory

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, proxypass

I have a multi tenancy application that runs on port 3000, this app will dinamically load and generate contents for variuos websites ex. `localhost:3000/webiste1.com/home` ,  `localhost:3000/webiste2.com/contacts` and so on.

Of course i would like to access website1 from `webiste1.com` and not only from `localhost:3000/webiste1.com`.
Basically i need that `webiste1.com` is able to serve contents from `localhost:3000/webiste1.com/`
Since websites are not static doing some rewrites is not enough, so im trying to use `proxy_pass`:

First attempt :

```
server {
    server_name webiste1.com;
    location ~ ^/_next {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3889;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
        
    location  ~ ^(.*)$ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3889/$host$request_uri; <--adding a slash at the end cause infinite loop
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/webiste1.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/webiste1.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = webiste1.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    server_name webiste1.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

If i visit  webiste1.com it redirects to webiste1.com/webiste1.com

Second attempt :

```
server {
    server_name webiste1.com;
    location ~ ^/_next {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3889;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
        
    location  ~ ^(.*)$ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3889/$host; <-- try to pass $host only
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

    }


}
```

If i visit website1.com it seems to works, content from `localhost:3000/website1.com` is served, however if i visit `website1.com./some/path` the proxy still serve content from `localhost:3000/website1.com` while it should serve content from `localhost:3000/website1.com/some/path`.
How can i make that `webistes1.com/any/path` is proxied from `localhost:3000/website1.com/any/path` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that that `proxy_pass` destination is fixed in your second configuration.

This approach should work:

```
server {
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3889/$host/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

As described in [proxy_pass documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass), here nginx replaces the part of normalized request URI specified in `location` with the URI specified in `proxy_pass`.

That is, in this case, the URL `https://example.com/` is translated to `http://127.0.0.1:3889/example.com/`.

And `https://example.com/123/` is translated to `http://127.0.0.1:3889/example.com/123`.

Comment: This doesnt seems to works it will append the hostname  to the url and then i get ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error

Comment: Also @Tero Kilkanen i need to load content from `http://127.0.0.1:3889/example.com/123` when visiting `https://example.com/123/`

Comment: Are you sure your application is handling the situation correctly? Please share output of `curl -v https://example.com/` with this config.

Comment: i got `curl : Error from temote server: (308) Permanent Redirect.` can be that ssl redirect is a problem? i've updated original post with ssl redirect

Comment: Your application is making this redirect for some reason.